# while compiling inline assembly in c using gcc with -g flag compiler is throwing "output operand constraint lacks"

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

calling fucntions from main 
global declarations int A=0, B=0, C=0;

```
void load()
{
        system("clear");
        printf("Enter 2 values: ");
        scanf("%d %d",&B,&C);
        __asm__ __volatile__("movl %1,%%ebx;"
            "movl  %2,%%ecx;"
                :: "b" (B) , "c" (C)
        );
        printf("Loaded Successfully. (press any key to continue.)");
        scanf("%d",&temp);
}
void Add()
{
    system("clear");
    __asm__("movl %ebx,%eax;"
        "addl %ecx,%eax;"
        :"=a" (Acc)
    );
    printf("Answer: %d (press any key to continue)",Acc);
    scanf("%d",&temp);
}
void Sub()
{
    system("clear");
    __asm__("movl %ebx,%eax;"
        "subl %ecx,%eax;"
        :"=a" (Acc)
    );
    printf("Answer: %d (press any key to continue)",Acc);
    scanf("%d",&temp);
}
void Mul()
{
    system("clear");
    __asm__("movl %ebx,%eax;"
        "imull %ecx,%eax;"
        :"=a" (Acc)
        );
    printf("Answer: %d (press any key to continue)",Acc);
    scanf("%d",&temp);
}
void Div()
{
    int rem;
    system("clear");
    __asm__("movl %0x0,%edx;"
        "movl %ebx,%eax;"
        "idivl %ecx"
        :"=a" (Acc) , "=r" (rem)
    );
    __asm__("movl %1, %eax"
        :: "a" (Acc)
    );
    printf("Quotient: %d Remainder= %d (press any key to continue)",Acc,rem);
    scanf("%d",&temp);
}
```

here's a code using inline assembly in c and while compiling with gcc -g it gives error :

```
test3.c: In function ‘main’:
test3.c:22:13: error: output operand constraint lacks ‘=’
             __asm__("movl %1,%ebx;" "movl  %2,%ecx;" : "r" (B): "r" (C));
             ^~~~~~~
test3.c:22:13: error: output operand constraint lacks ‘=’
test3.c:22:13: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 0
```

references from :

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15971/using-inline-assembly-in-c-c

Source Codes from the site is compiling perfectly but while compiling the above code it gives errors
Also tried **asm** **volatile** 
but it again gcc is throwing :

```
error: bad register name `%%eax'
```

Comment: `%%eax` isn't a register name.  `%eax`.  If you tried to use `%%eax` in the clobber list or somewhere other than the template of an Extended Asm statement, yes you'd get errors.  These inline asm statements are all broken garbage that don't declare clobbers on the registers they hard-code and modify, and they use `%eax` instead of `%%eax` inside asm templates so the compiler will treat that as trying to use a named operand that doesn't exists.  You need `%%` to get a literal percent sign into the compiler's asm output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for some links to docs, guides, and tutorials that are (hopefully) full of unsafe or broken examples.  The tutorial you linked starts with Basic Asm (no constraints) which you should never use.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended